# .NET 5 WebApp can not load multiple configuration json files

Tags: c#, json, web-applications, configuration, .net-5

I have these json configuration files:
appsettings.json -> common configuration

```
{
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

and appsettingsAmbiente.json -> specific environment configuration

```
"DbSettings": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "OracleWHB": "Data Source=xxx.aaa.bbb:1521/inte_t_client;User Id=TEST;Password=test;"
    },
    "QueryConfigTable": "SELECT CHIAVE, VALORE FROM NAT_WHB__CONFIG",
    "TabellaLog": "NAT_WHB__LOG"
},
"AppSettings": {
    "Ambiente": "produzione"
},
"UserSettings": {
    "ForzaUtente": false,
    "UtenteCorrente": {
        "Id": "1",
        "Nominativo": "Foo",
        "Ruolo": "Admin",
        "Matricola": "AAAAA9999"
    }
}
```

This is my Program.cs:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Serilog;
    using UI.WebApp.ConfigurationMiddleware;
    
    namespace UI.WebApp
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .AddCommandLine(args)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettingsAmbiente.json")
                    .Build();
    
                CreateHostBuilder(args, configuration).Build().Run();
            }
    
            public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args, IConfiguration  conf) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseSerilog()
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .CaptureStartupErrors(captureStartupErrors: true); // per intercettare errrori generati prima del metodo Configure dello startup
                    })
    
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                    {
                        config.AddDbConfiguration(options =>
                        {
                            options.ConnectionStrings = new Connectionstrings
                            {
                                OracleWHB = conf.GetValue<string>("DbSettings:ConnectionStrings:OracleWHB")
                            };
                            options.QueryConfigTable = conf.GetValue<string>("DbSettings:QueryConfigTable");
                        });
                    });
        }
    }
```

This is my Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UI.WebApp.ExceptionMiddleware;
using UI.WebApp.LogMiddleware;

namespace UI.WebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public static LoggingLevelSwitch loggingLevelSwitch = new ();
        public static LoggingFilterSwitch loggingFilterSwitch = new();

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDevExpressControls();
            MapSettings(services);

            services.AddTransient<IUserManagement, UserManagement>();
            services.AddTransient<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services
            .AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.ConfigureReportingServices(configurator => {
                configurator.UseAsyncEngine();
                configurator.ConfigureWebDocumentViewer(viewerConfigurator => {
                    viewerConfigurator.UseCachedReportSourceBuilder();
                });
            });

            LogEventLevel.TryParse(LogSettings.Current.DefaultLogLevel, out LogEventLevel logLevel);
            loggingLevelSwitch.MinimumLevel = logLevel;
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(loggingLevelSwitch)
            .Filter.ControlledBy(loggingFilterSwitch)
            .Destructure.JsonNetTypes()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
            .WriteTo.Oracle(cfg =>
                cfg.WithSettings(DbSettings.Current.ConnectionStrings.OracleWHB
                                , tableSpaceAndTableName: DbSettings.Current.TabellaLog
                                )
                .UseBurstBatch()
                .CreateSink()
                )
            .CreateLogger();

            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));

            services.AddSingleton<Serilog.ILogger>(Log.Logger);
            services.AddNHibernate();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseDevExpressControls();
            app.UseExceptionHandlerMiddleware(Log.Logger, errorPagePath: "/Error/HandleError" , respondWithJsonErrorDetails: true);
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/HandleError/{0}");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            var jsnlogConfiguration = new JsnlogConfiguration();
            app.UseJSNLog(new CustomLoggingAdapter(loggerFactory), jsnlogConfiguration);

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //to exclude noisy handlers from logging, such as UseStaticFiles(), by placing UseSerilogRequestLogging() after them.
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(opts => opts.EnrichDiagnosticContext = LogHelper.EnrichFromRequest);

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        private void MapSettings(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            UserSettings userSettings = new();
            Configuration.Bind("UserSettings", userSettings);
            services.AddSingleton(userSettings);

            DbSettings dbSettings = new();
            Configuration.Bind("DbSettings", dbSettings);
            services.AddSingleton(dbSettings);

            LogSettings logSettings = new();
            Configuration.Bind("LogSettings", logSettings);
            services.AddSingleton(logSettings);

            AppSettings appSettings = new();
            Configuration.Bind("AppSettings", appSettings);
            services.AddSingleton(appSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I run project, the Program.cs configure correctly the application classes (UserSettings, DbSettings etc) binding content of appsettings.json and appsettingsAmbiente.json as indicated; after that, when Startup.cs is executed, the only file used to bind (throught MapSettings method) is appsettings.json like if the application lost settings defined in Main void of Program.cs.

Can someone explain me the reason and how to maintain settings in Startup.cs too (both files appsettings.json and apsettingsAmbiente.json)?

Comment: Why are you creating a seperate config builder? There are other ways to get the values when configuring the db. But if you **must** (why??), either add `config.Add(conf)` in your ConfigureAppConfiguration callback to add your first configuration into the one ultimately used by the Host *or* re-add the json files individually in the very same callback

Comment: Also your `MapSettings` method is absurd. Use `Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"))` to leverage the Options infrastructure like everything else. If you *really* need those as direct singletons you can follow it up with something like `services.AddSingleton<AppSettings>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>().Value)` but I strongly recommend that you leverage the mechanisms in place, which practically everything else is built around